# Smart video capturing tool to facilitate wayfinding

Tags: video, video-recording

Is there a video capturing tool that is smart enough to understand the details that were captured and then generates a way finding path to certain locations in the video?
Perhaps not.

If none exist, is there a tool that facilitates naming and storing each location in the video footage, so that I can later cut & play the video till these certain locations ?

Answer (score 1):

The video analysis capabilities you describe constitute a whole active field of research/engineering called [(visual) simultaneous localization and mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping) (SLAM or VSLAM for short). The pathfinding would be the easy part compared to constructing the map from video data.

Many frameworks/tools/libraries for such analyses exist. To my knowledge, none of them are really reliable or easy to use at this point in time (2023) and a lot of them need powerful hardware to perform the necessary processing in a reasonable amount of time. But I could be wrong and it can be fun to experiment with them yourself in any case.

You can find some freely available open-source VSLAM frameworks, libraries and tools e.g. under the [visual-slam topic on GitHub](https://github.com/topics/visual-slam). For instance, [stella_vslam](https://github.com/stella-cv/stella_vslam) is one example, but there are many more and new ones come out all the time.

I expect that the most polished of this kind of software is being developed behind closed doors for commercial/industrial/military use - not something ordinary people can get their hands on.